# Activity leaked

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks

Suppose you have an app that has two activities: activity A (the launcher) with a button that launches activity B. The code of activity B that matters is:

```
final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView(....);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException( Thread thread, Throwable ex )
        {
        }
    });
}
```

Activity B loads some bitmaps for its interface. It does NOT restore the old default uncaught exception handler on its exit. Doing A->B->A->B... causes an out of memory exception, because activity B is leaked. Why exactly activity B is leaked?

Comment: Do you find any solutions ? @Marco Masci

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is the wrong architecture. For chained search you should only ever have a single instance of each `Activity`. You should flip between the different `Activity` instances by calling `startActivity()` and setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` in the `Intent` you use. Also add the data you want to display as "extras" in the `Intent`.

To be able to use the BACK button to back through the chain (no matter how long it is), each `Activity` should manage a stack that contains the data that it needs to recreate the page whenever the user backs into it. In `onCreate()` and in `onNewIntent()` the data (from the "extras") should be pushed onto the stack and displayed. You then override `onBackPressed()` and go back to the previous `Activity` by calling `startActivity()`, and setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` in the `Intent` you use. You also add an "extra" to the `Intent` that indicates the user wants to "go back". In `onBackPressed()` you should also discard the top element off the data stack of the `Activity` that is being left. This will ensure that the stack is correct when the user then backs into this `Activity`.

In `onNewIntent()` if the user just backed into the `Activity`, you just display the data that is already on top of the stack of managed data.

In this way, you only ever have one instance of each `Activity`, the user can chain all day through the set of activities and the BACK button always works and you don't have to worry about running out of memory.

Trying to accomplish this using `taskAffinity` or `Intent` flags or similar will not work. Don't waste your time. It is also bad programming style.

I hope this is clear.
and for memory exception use
add manifest

android > v3

```
<application
    ....
       android:largeHeap="true">
```